# Assist with setting up client and server

Tags: c#, frameworks, client-server, communication, xml-rpc

Probably a simple question but can't find help online. I have written a checkers application in c# and am trying to use xmlrpc.net version 2.5 to establish a connection so that one user (client) can type in the ip address of the other computer (server) and be able to send messages back and forth to update the board changes.

Here is some pseudo-code of what I am trying to do,

```
public void startConnecting()
{
    //set up xml-rpc to connect to specified ip address


    //if successful start the game
    //start a receive message thread
    //sendMsg(name);

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //start the search for the ip address stored in textBox2
{
   name = textBox1.Text;
   startConnecting();
}
public void sendMsg(string s)
{
   while (true)
   //send msg
 }
```

Comment: Out of interest: why have you chosen xml-rpc rather than WCF?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "XML-RPC.NET C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.